# Passing integer from one method to another

Tags: java, arrays

Trying to write a program with two methods. First one takes an integer and prints its divisors as well as the sum of its divisors, the second is a boolean function that returns if the given integer is equal to the sum of its divisors (a perfect number).

I have the first method done fine but I want to take the integer sum from it and use it in the second method, is this even possible? Iv spent about quite a while trying to research it with no success.

As usual any and all advice appreciated. Code so far is below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class arrayTest {

public static int sumFacs(int n) {

    int sumDiv[] = new int[50];
    int c = 0;
    int sum=0;

    if(n<0){
        System.out.println("Sorry I dont do negatives!");
    }

    else {

    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        int j = n%i;

        if(j==0){
            System.out.println( i + " is a divisor of " + n + "\n");
            sumDiv[c] = i;
            c++;
        }

    }

    for (int i=0; i<sumDiv.length; i++){
    sum += sumDiv[i];}

    System.out.println("The sum of the divisors of " + n + " is: " + sum);

}
    return sum;
}

public static boolean isPerfect(int n, int sum) {

boolean b = (n == sum);
if(b){
    System.out.println( n + " is a perfect number.");
}

else {
    System.out.println( n + " is not a perfect number.");
}
}




public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer.");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();

 sumFacs(n);
 int sumDivisors = sumFacs(n);
 System.out.println(isDivisors(sumFacs(n), n));

 isPerfect(n, sum);
}
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code above, still having a 'cannot find symbol' error in line 67. Cannot spot the error myself!

Comment: It seems that you do not have the `isDivisors` method (that is what is causing the cannot find symbol). Even if you fix that, the code will still not work because the `isPerfect` method does not return anything. If you would like to keep it like so, please refer to the answer provided by @SeanF.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sumFacs` returns an integer, so you can definitely use whatever it yields in your `isPerfect` method. As you are doing it now, you are passing the same number to the methods. To do what you want, you will need to do something like so:

```
int sumFacsResult = sumFacs(n);     //Take whatever value sumFacs yields, store it in sumFacsResult
System.out.println(isPerfect(sumFacsResult, n);    //Take the result of sumFacs and pass it to the isPerfect method
```

or shorthand:

```
System.out.println(isPerfect(sumFacs(n), n));    //It is usually recommended to use the other approach, for readability purposed.
```

And your `isPerfect` method should be something like so:

```
public static boolean isPerfect(int sum, int number)
{
    return sum == number;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code above, still having a 'cannot find symbol' error in line 67. Cannot spot the error myself!

Answer (score 0):

your `sumFacs(int n)` has a return type of int and you are returning sum but where you call that method you are not setting it to anything so what you want to do is:

```
int foo = sumFacs(n);  
isPerfect(n,foo);
```

and make your isperfect class

```
public static void isPerfect(int n, int foo)
{ 
  if((n==foo) 
  {     
    System.out.println( n + " is a perfect number."); 
  }else{    
    System.out.println( n + " is not a perfect number."); 
  }
}
```

However this would all be easier in one class not two

Comment: You would need to place return statements in the method for this to compile. Alternatively, you could make it `void`, but it does not seem to be what the OP is after.

Comment: @npinti indeed you would, was a typo more than anything :) im not sure if its what OP is after if he does still want a return type your example is good for that.